# how to disable extra by default when i start up Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When i given Ctrl + H. It's disabled. But again i will open new file. i got the same issues. so how to disable extra by default when i start up Photoshop?
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you mean by "disable extra". Please edit your question as it's not clear at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the grid. You can disable it  at the View > Show menu. Save your new file with "Save as" when the grid first is disabled by removing the V from View > Show > Grid. Then new files should start without the grid.